# PowerShell script to restore SQL Server database from one server to another have different drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, database-restore

I am trying to write a script which restores the database from remote machine to a new SQL Server. My old SQL Server has data drive as volume `D:` and new SQL Server has data drive as `E:` so can someone help me in restoring the database from PS to other drive location?

Backup is placed inside new SQL Server `E:\migration` folder from where I am trying to restore it. Below is what I have tried which works well with same folder structure.

```
# Defining the server Name

Write-Host " Initiating the SQL Server Install"
$Servers = Read-Host "Please specify DB Server Name"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers{

$INSTANCENAME = Read-Host "Please specify DB Server Instance Name , ex:- DBXXXXINST01"
$VOLNAME = Read-Host "Please specify DB Server InstanceVolume Name , ex:- XXXXINST01"

$ServerInstance = Read-Host "Please specify DB Server Instance Name , ex:- dbxx\DBXXXXINST01"

import-module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking

Write-Host " Initiating the DB creation/configuration"
Write-Host "Creating SQL folder"

$setupFolder = "E:\$VOLNAME\SQL"

New-Item -Path $setupFolder -type directory -Force 

$backupRoot = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\migration\DB_Backup\1234inst01\"
$datafilesDest = "E:\$VOLNAME\SQL\"
$logfilesDest = "E:\$VOLNAME\SQL\"

## For each folder in the backup root directory...
#
foreach($folder in $backupRoot)
{   
    # Get the most recent .bak files for all databases...
    $backupFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter "*.bak" -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

    # For each .bak file...
    foreach ($backupFile in $backupFiles)
    {
        # Restore the header to get the database name...
        $query = "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'"+$backupFile.FullName+"'"
        $headerInfo = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query $query
        $databaseName = $headerInfo.DatabaseName

        # Restore the file list to get the logical filenames of the database files...
        $query = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'"+$backupFile.FullName+"'"
        $files = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query $query

        # Differentiate data files from log files...
        $dataFile = $files | Where-Object -Property Type -EQ "D"
        $logFile = $files | Where-Object -Property Type -EQ "L"

        # Set some variables...
        $dataFileName = $dataFile.LogicalName
        $logFileName = $logFile.LogicalName

        # Set the destination of the restored files...
        $dataFileFullPath = $datafilesDest+"\"+$dataFileName+".mdf"
        $logFileFullPath = $logfilesDest+"\"+$logFileName+".ldf"

        # Perform the database restore... and then go around the loop.
        Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $databaseName -BackupFile $backupFile.FullName -ReplaceDatabase
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [`RelocateFile` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/restore-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps#examples) of `Restore-SqlDatabase` to achieve this.

I haven't tested this but if you are happy with the new physical file names your question code constructs this should work:

```
$relocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($dataFile.LogicalName, $dataFileFullPath)
$relocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($logFile.LogicalName, $logFileFullPath)

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $databaseName -BackupFile $backupFile.FullName -ReplaceDatabase -RelocateFile @($relocateData, $relocateLog)
```

Edit:

Depending on your configuration of powershell sql modules, this might fail if powershell instantiates the `RelocateFile` objects as the wrong versions.

Fix is to force the versions to match by [checking the assembly version that implements the `Restore-SqlDatabase` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779693/909199).

Comment: I tried this and i am getting Cannot bind parameter 'RelocateFile'. Cannot convert the "$RelocateData" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restore-SqlDatabase], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.RestoreSqlDatabaseCommand.. Not sure where i am missing with logic .. Since i am trying to do this remotely so it shld work in an ideal case..

Comment: The error you get indicates a problem passing the `-RelocateFile` parameter properly.
Try setting this to a variable, then check the variable's type:
`$rf = @($relocateData, $RelocateLog); $rf | get-member` - should return `TypeName: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile`

Comment: I already checked that and type name is same as what you mentioned.. even after placing it into variable i am getting same issue :- Cannot bind parameter 'RelocateFile'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" value of type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" to type 
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile". FYI.. this is sql 2016

Comment: The answer code works in a SQL 2017 container. There's answer on dba stackexchange for 2016 that suggests [restoring files separately](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/170707)

Comment: I also found a related problem about versioning of the `RelocateFile` objects, your latest error sounds more like that one.